# `Transpose` nested `Association`

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations

Say I have a nested Association like this one:

```
assc = <|1-><|a1-><|opt->0.734149,fit->0.56074|>,a2-><|opt->-0.268146,fit->-0.536405|>,a3-><|opt->23.1298,fit->12.5986|>|>,2-><|a1-><|opt->9.53617*10^-8,fit->0.337033|>,a2-><|opt->-0.0000357894,fit->-0.250143|>,a3-><|opt->2.76778*10^-6,fit->-7.54487|>|>,3-><|a1-><|opt->0.80264,fit->0.526605|>,a2-><|opt->-0.0159458,fit->-0.646664|>,a3-><|opt->45.9309,fit->-12.3689|>|>,4-><|a1-><|opt->0.913804,fit->0.741119|>,a2-><|opt->-0.145981,fit->-0.808445|>,a3-><|opt->11.7184,fit->2.29814|>|>,5-><|a1-><|opt->0.702291,fit->0.528957|>,a2-><|opt->-0.0902689,fit->-0.25787|>,a3-><|opt->11.4746,fit->12.7903|>|>|>
```

whose `Dataset` view looks like this:
[image]

I'd like to `Transpose` the Dataset to rearrange its levels as the similar operation over its values:

```
Transpose[(assc //. assc : Association[v__] :> Values[assc]), {1, 3, 2}]
```

However, I find such `Transpose` operation is not possible over an `Association`:

```
Transpose[assc, {1, 3, 2}]
```

[image]

What is the proper way in Mathematica to do that?

Comment: You could try `Transpose /@ assc` instead.

Comment: Thanks @CarlWoll. The case I raised is actually a simple one: I need some workaround for higher dimensional datasets. And I just learnt the current `Association` is actually atomic, which might cause this more difficult.

Comment: `Dataset` supports `Transpose`, you might want to try `assc // Dataset // #[;; , Transpose] & // Normal`.