# How to make arbitrary transpositions of associations and datasets

Tags: expression-manipulation, dataset, associations

Is there a general `Transpose` for `Dataset`/`Association` that will transpose arbitrary levels, such as

```
Transpose[array, perm]
```

which will permute the levels of `array` according to the permutation `perm`? One seems to be able to use `Transpose[ds]` to transpose levels 1 and 2 and `Map[Query@Transpose, ds, {n}]` to transpose levels `n+1` and `n+2`. But they only work on "adjacent" levels. To transpose levels 1 and 3 (i.e. `perm = {3, 2, 1}`), I seem to have to do something like the following

```
Transpose[Transpose /@ Transpose@ assoc]
Transpose[ds][Transpose, Transpose]
```

Is there a general way to do this for an arbitrary permutation of the levels of the data?

(I give a solution below, but as I'm learning how to use `Dataset`, I figure there are better ways.)

Related: [Association of Associations : how to permute level 1 and level 2 keys?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86492/association-of-associations-how-to-permute-level-1-and-level-2-keys) and [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86492/association-of-associations-how-to-permute-level-1-and-level-2-keys#comment235441_86498).

Comment: Possible duplicate, but no answers: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166585/transpose-nested-association

Comment: Hi Michael, do you mind if I temporarily downvote some of your questions/answers (to test something about the rep accounting)?

Comment: @kglr Okay. (extra chars)

Comment: thank you Michael. Done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Definitions

Here is an alternative implementation using the 
[Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository) 
functions
[`AssociationKeyFlatten`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AssociationKeyFlatten) and
[`ToAssociations`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ToAssociations)  (submitted by WRI personnel) and
the function `meMerge` (`localMerge`) from 
the [answer by andre314](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212100/34008):

```
Clear[TransposeAssoc];
TransposeAssoc[assoc_Association, perm_?PermutationListQ] :=
  Block[{assoc2, assoc3, LocalMerge},
   LocalMerge[x : {_Association ..}] := Merge[x, LocalMerge]; 
   LocalMerge[{x_}] := x;
   assoc2 = ResourceFunction["AssociationKeyFlatten"][assoc];
   assoc3 = KeyMap[Permute[#, perm] &, assoc2];
   LocalMerge[
    ResourceFunction["ToAssociations"]@
     KeyValueMap[Fold[{#2 -> #1} &, #2, Reverse@#1] &, assoc3]]
  ];
```

### Step-by-step run

[image]

Comment: Hi, Anton. Thanks! I already upvoted, but I just noticed that the output is not quite right.  The list of associations needs to be merged in just the way @andre314's does.  In fact, using his `myMerge` function with your `TransposeAssoc` yields the desired output `myMerge@TransposeAssoc[assoc, {3, 1, 4, 2}]`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GeFkF.png

Comment: Ah, yes, my application of `ResourceFunction["ToAssociations"]` is not right. I will fix my answer tonight/tomorrow.

Comment: There is a `ResourceFunction["AssociationTranspose"]` now

Comment: @matheorem Good to know!

Answer (score 9):

If you factor a permuation `perm` into a product of cycles of the form $(j\ k)$ with $k=j+1$, then the permuation can be effected by `Query` and `Transpose`.

Functions:

```
adjacentCycles[perm] (* factors perm into "adjacent" 2-cycles *)
dsTranspose[x, perm] (* like Transpose[x, perm],
                        but x is a Dataset or Association *)
```

Code:

```
(* adjacentCycles
 *   factor permutations into cycles of the form (n n+1)
 *)
adjacentCycles[p_?PermutationListQ] := 
  Flatten@iAdjacentCycles[PermutationCycles[p]];
adjacentCycles[c : Cycles[{{__Integer} ..}]] := 
  Flatten@iAdjacentCycles[c];
iAdjacentCycles[Cycles[c : {}]] := {};
iAdjacentCycles[Cycles[c : {c1_, c2__}]] :=(*Join@@*)
  iAdjacentCycles /@ Cycles@*List /@ c;
iAdjacentCycles[Cycles[{c : {x_, y_, z__}}]] :=(*Join@@*)
  iAdjacentCycles /@ Cycles@*List /@ Reverse@Partition[c, 2, 1];
iAdjacentCycles[Cycles[{c : {x_, y_}}]] := Module[{a, b},
   {a, b} = MinMax[{x, y}];
   With[{factors = 
      Cycles@*List /@ Reverse@Partition[Range[a, b], 2, 1]},
    Reverse@Rest[factors]~Join~factors]
   ];

ClearAll[dsTranspose];
dsTranspose[assoc_Association, perm_?PermutationListQ] := 
  With[{res = dsTranspose[Dataset@assoc, perm]},
   Normal@res /; Dataset`ValidDatasetQ[res]
   ];
dsTranspose[ds_Dataset, perm_?PermutationListQ] :=
  Module[{
    xps,  (* perm factored as 2-cycle transpositions *)
    xpFN, (* applies Transpose or Query[Transpose] to appropriate level *)
    res},
   xps = adjacentCycles@perm;
   xps = xps[[All, 1, 1, 1]] - 1; (* levels to be transposed *)
   xpFN[0] = Transpose;
   xpFN[n_Integer?Positive] := 
    Map[Check[Query[Transpose][#], 
        Throw[$Failed, dsTranspose]] &, #, {n}] &;
   res = Catch[Fold[xpFN[#2][#1] &, ds, xps], dsTranspose];
   res /; Dataset`ValidDatasetQ[res]
   ];
```

Example:

```
assoc = Fold[AssociationThread[#2 -> #1] &, "X", 
  Reverse@Table[ToString[10 i + j], {i, 4}, {j, 2}]]
(*
<|"11" ->
    <|"21" -> <|"31" -> <|"41" -> "X", "42" -> "X"|>, 
                "32" -> <|"41" -> "X", "42" -> "X"|>|>, 
      "22" -> <|"31" -> <|"41" -> "X", "42" -> "X"|>, 
                "32" -> <|"41" -> "X", "42" -> "X"|>|>|>, 
  "12" ->
    <|"21" -> <|"31" -> <|"41" -> "X", "42" -> "X"|>, 
                "32" -> <|"41" -> "X", "42" -> "X"|>|>, 
      "22" -> <|"31" -> <|"41" -> "X", "42" -> "X"|>, 
                "32" -> <|"41" -> "X", "42" -> "X"|>|>|>|>
*)

dsTranspose[assoc, {3, 1, 4, 2}]
(*                                     (* perm:         *)
<|"21" ->                              (*  level 2 -> 1 *)
    <|"41" ->                          (*  level 4 -> 2 *)
              <|"11" ->                (*  level 1 -> 3 *)
                        <|"31" -> "X", (*  level 3 -> 4 *)
                                       "32" -> "X"|>,
                "12" -> <|"31" -> "X", "32" -> "X"|>|>, 
      "42" -> <|"11" -> <|"31" -> "X", "32" -> "X"|>, 
                "12" -> <|"31" -> "X", "32" -> "X"|>|>|>, 
  "22" ->
    <|"41" -> <|"11" -> <|"31" -> "X", "32" -> "X"|>, 
                "12" -> <|"31" -> "X", "32" -> "X"|>|>, 
      "42" -> <|"11" -> <|"31" -> "X", "32" -> "X"|>, 
                "12" -> <|"31" -> "X", "32" -> "X"|>|>|>|>
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that doesn't need to flatten the whole tree of data.

Let's take the example of moving the level 1 keys at the level 3, on the data `assoc` of your self-answer :

```
assoc = Fold[AssociationThread[#2 -> #1] &, "X", 
  Reverse@Table[ToString[10 i + j], {i, 4}, {j, 2}]]
```

Here is a function `showAssocListTree` that will be usefull to show clearly how associations are nested. It's just a formatting function. It is useless to understand it:

```
showAssocListTree = RightComposition[
  # //. List[content___] :>  Prepend[List1 /@ List1[content], "List"] &
  , # /. List1 -> List &
  , # //. as : Association[___] :>  
     Prepend[List @@@ Normal[as], "Ass."] &
  , TableForm[#] &
  , ToBoxes
  , # //. GridBox[{{"\"List\"", ___}, r___}, r01___] :> 
     RowBox[{RotationBox[
        StyleBox["\"List\"", FontVariations -> {"Underline" -> True}],
         BoxRotation -> Pi/2], "["(*StyleBox["[",FontWeight\[Rule] 
       "Bold"]*), GridBox[{r}, r01]}] &
  , # //. GridBox[{{"\"Ass.\"", ___}, r___}, r01___] :> 
     RowBox[{"-> ", RotationBox["\"Ass.\"", BoxRotation -> Pi/2], 
       StyleBox["[", FontWeight -> "Bold"], GridBox[{r}, r01]}] &
  , # /. RowBox[{"-> ", r___}] :>  RowBox[{r}] &
  , # //. InterpretationBox[x_, ___] :> x &
  , # /. RowBox[{a___, RotationBox["\"Ass.\"", BoxRotation -> Pi/2], 
       r___}] :>  
     RowBox[{a, RotationBox["\"Association\"", BoxRotation -> Pi/2], 
       r}] &
  , RawBoxes
  , Style[#, GridBoxOptions -> { GridBoxDividers -> None}, 
    SpanMaxSize -> DirectedInfinity[1]] &
  ];
```

your data formatted :

```
assoc  // showAssocListTree
```

[image]

Insertion of level 1 data at level 3 :

```
listOfAssoc=KeyValueMap[
 Function[{k, v}, Map[Association[k -> #] &, v, {2}]], assoc];  

listOfAssoc //showAssocListTree
```

[image]

Note that the outer `Association` has been transformed in a `List`.

Now, the built-in function `Merge` will be applied. This function only merge two successive levels. So, a recursive function is first created. Note that when applied, this recursive function will explode exponentially, but in most cases, it's better than to flatten the whole tree, and there are probably ways to circumvent this problem.

```
ClearAll[myMerge]
myMerge[x : {_Association ..}] := Merge[x, myMerge]
myMerge[{x_}] := x  


myMerge[listOfAssoc ] //showAssocListTree
```

[image]

This approach can be generalised to the general case. For example {3, 1, 4, 2} could be decomposed as {1, 2, 3, 4} -> {1, 3, 4, 2} -> {3, 1, 4, 2}

[inspiration source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86565/5467)

Comment: For those who are interested in the (dirty) code of myNicePresentation, be aware that it uses SpanMaxSize & Co which is not integrated into the long - 
 term Wolfram Language (according to the documentation)

Comment: This looks great.  If by "interverting levels 1 and 3" you mean switching them, I should point out it actually does a cyclic permutation `{2, 3, 1}` of `{1, 2, 3}`, but that should reduce the number of iterations compared to my solution. In general, `KeyValueMap[Function[{k, v}, Map[Association[k -> #] &, n - 1, {2}]], #] &` cyclically permutes the first `n` levels.

Comment: @MichaelE2 it's an error, now corrected. I prefer not to use the word "permutation" (for non-mathematician or mathematics allergics).